# Link GitHub repository in Documentation page

Tags: discussion, documentation

I would like to add some documentation to Stack Overflow which covers the topic of how to set up a dedicated Google App Engine project.

I have a working example of such a project in my public GitHub Repository and I got the idea to link this GitHub project in my documentation example.

Is this a practical way for a piece of Documentation? Or should I avoid
links to GitHub and use screenshots or code examples from my GitHub Project?

I read the introduction for the Documentation page but I did not get any hints about linking Github repositories.

Comment: SO documentation should not  aggregate links for 3rd party sources IMO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your item on Documentation should be self-contained. It should not rely on links to external resources.

If your project on GitHub illustrates the point, you can add it for reference. But, do this **only** if the purpose is to provide a reference and "further reading".
If the purpose is to draw more attention to your own project on GitHub, that is self-promotion, and we don't want that.